# Return certain field in Symfony with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have the code

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->hydrate(false)
                   ->select('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3', 'param_4');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->execute()
                 ->toArray();
```

I expect this to return a structures like as

```
{
   {
      "param_1": p1,
      "param_2": p2,
      "param_3": p3,
      "param_4": p4
   }
}
```

But that return

```
{
  "58f518de92614b342800002d": {
    "_id": {
      "$id": "58f518de92614b342800002d"
    },
    "param_1": p1,
    "param_2": p2,
    "param_3": p3,
    "param_4": p4
  }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$results = $query->getScalarResult();` ?

Comment: Method not found.

Answer (score 0):

I added eagerCursor(true) and work.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
           ->hydrate(false)
           ->eagerCursor(true)
           ->select('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3', 'param_4');
```

Thanks for help!